# HLSL's Tex2D for GLSL?

Tags: shaders, glsl, hlsl

I am trying to port a HLSL shader to GLSL. I'm just not quite sure how to convert this line:

```
  outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(-4.0 * pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.05;
```

It's mostly the Tex2D I'm having trouble with. In GLSL, it seems to work differently.

I'm porting a horizontal blur

```
 texture al_tex;
   sampler2D s = sampler_state {
      texture = <al_tex>;
   };

   int tWidth;
   int tHeight;
   float blurSize = 5.0;
   float4 ps_main(VS_OUTPUT Input) : COLOR0
   {
      float2 pxSz = float2(1.0 / tWidth,1.0 / tHeight);
      float4 outC = 0;
      float outA = 0;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(-4.0 * pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.05;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(-3.0 * pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.09;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(-2.0 * pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.12;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(-pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.15;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(0,0)).a * 0.16;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.15;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(2.0 * pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.12;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(3.0 * pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.09;
      outA += Input.Color.a * tex2D(s, Input.TexCoord.xy + float2(4.0 * pxSz.x * blurSize,0)).a * 0.05;

     outC.a = outA;

      return outC;
   }
```

Thanks

Comment: If that's a D3D9 shader it will look a bit different because of the different pixel<->texel mapping http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb219690%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `texture2D (...)` on older versions of OpenGL (before OpenGL 3.0) and `texture (...)` on newer versions.

Newer versions of GLSL (1.3+, which corresponds to OpenGL 3.0) are nice about this, they automatically determine the texture overload based on sampler type and texture coordinates you use. So you don't have to do `textureCube (...)`, `texture3D (...)`, etc.

Also, use proper texel centers when porting from D3D9. You don't need a half-texel offset in OpenGL or Direct3D 10.

Answer (score 0):

The GLSL function you're looking for is called [texture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/texture.xml).